# Xelement.Element(string) always returning null

Tags: c#, xml

I have an Xelement which looks like:

```
<headers batchid="123456" xmlns="http://api.temp.com/ns/">
  <header uri="https://api.temp.com/v1.0/headers/147852" id="147852" /> 
  </headers>
```

I'm trying to read the "uri" attribute. When I tried :

```
var temp = xmlResponse.Attribute("uri");
```

it kept return me null.

So I tried:

```
var temp = xmlResponse.Element("header");
var temp2 = xmlResponse.Element("headers");
```

and they are also returning null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're ignoring the namespace of the element. Due to the `xmlns="..."`, both the `headers` and `header` elements are in a namespace of `"http://api.temp.com/ns/"`. Fortunately, LINQ to XML makes this really easy to fix:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://api.temp.com/ns/";
var temp = xmlResponse.Element(ns + "headers");
var temp2 = temp.Element(ns + "header");
```

(Note that the `header` element is nested within the `headers` element, hence why I'm calling `temp.Element` to get at it.)

Comment: I have tried `XNamespace ns = "http://api.temp.com/ns/";
var temp = xmlResponse.Element(ns + "headers")`; but its still returning null

Comment: `var temp2 = xmlResponse.Element(ns + "messageheader")`; worked

Comment: @YagneshCangi: Then the XML isn't what you said it was. It doesn't help that we've no idea what `xmlResponse` is - an XDocument? An XElement? Which one? If you'd posted a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem to start with, we could have helped you better. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's Xelement. I thought the first line will make it clear. Sorry.

Comment: @YagneshCangi: No, it's particularly unclear because you have an example of a line of code which tries to *get* the `headers` element from `xmlResponse`...